# second texture not showing up in glsl shader

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

I'm very confused why I can't get my texture to display in my shader using GLSL.

First, I render a flat color to an FBO and copy it to my texture.

```
        GLuint textureId;
        glGenTextures(1, &textureId);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        _transferFbo->bind();
        glClearColor(1,0.5,.5,1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, 256, 256, 0);

        _transferFbo->release();
```

If I use this texture without a shader using glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) it works fine.  I've also tried using it in a debug shader with a quad that fills the screen and again it works, so I assume my texture is at least partially correct.

I then try to use the texture in a shader where I'm already using another texture and I get nothing when sampling it.

```
_meshShader->bind();
_meshShader->setUniformValue("objToWorld", objToWorld);
_meshShader->setUniformValue("cameraPV", cameraProjViewM);
_meshShader->setUniformValue("meshTexture", 0);
_meshShader->setUniformValue("paintTexture", 1);
_meshShader->setUniformValue("paintFboWidth", PAINT_FBO_WIDTH);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _meshTextures[mesh]); // not working
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _paintFbo->texture()); // working
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

In my shader I've mapped the mesh uvs to the output color and the values seem reasonable.  However when I try sampling from that texture all I get is black.  I've even tried hard-coding the UV value to .5,.5 just to make sure I could get a flat value, but again it's black.  I've also tried swapping the texture units so the paint texture is first, but that doesn't change.  What could I possibly be doing wrong in this shader that makes this texture return black?

```
                   #version 120
                   varying vec3 worldPos;
                   varying vec2 uv;
                   uniform vec3 cameraPos;
                   uniform sampler2D meshTexture;
                   uniform sampler2D paintTexture;
                   uniform int paintFboWidth;
                   void main() {
                       vec2 paintUvs = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x/paintFboWidth, gl_FragCoord.y/paintFboWidth);

                       gl_FragColor = texture2D(paintTexture, paintUvs);

                       // this is just for testing -- this half of the quad is
                       // always black
                       if (uv.t > 0.5) gl_FragColor = texture2D(meshTexture, uv);
                   }
```

**EDIT**

Here's a link to the full OpenGL code.
https://github.com/strattonbrazil/paintbug/blob/master/glview.cpp

And here's a screenshot where you can see the red texture working and the black portion, which should be a fleshy color is coming across black.

[image: quad with half of texture working]

Comment: Are you using mipmapping (without generating the mipmaps for the FBO texture)?

Comment: We need to see the code of how you actually set up the textures. BTW, doing some FBO rendering and then a copy to texture is probably not the most efficient approach.

Comment: I notice you're dividing by an integer in your shader. I'd assume the compiler would convert the `int` to a `float`, but I've had problems with that before. If it's actually converting the coordinate to an `int` instead, then it would always result in 0 from the division, meaning it would always sample the first pixel. Might not be the issue, but probably worth a check.

Comment: @GuyRT No, I'm not using mipmapping.  It seems to work for the other FBO I use though.  Because I'm getting the correct UVs in my shader and can use the texture outside in fixed-pipeline mode I assume the problem is with my shader or multitexturing setup.

Comment: @user1118321 That is to compute the screen space UVs for the red texture.  Those UVs and the texture lookup are correct.